# PWM module and inrush current from motor

Tags: pwm, inrush-current

I'm trying to setup a power feed for a milling machine using an old DeWalt drill motor.

I've got a 13.8v 20A power supply and a Kemo M195 20A PWM module.

My concern is the inrush current from the motor, Using a clamp on meter I get peaks of around 22-24A on starting. Is around 5A running with no load.

Could the inrush damage the PWM module?

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Answer (score 1):

A good PWM module would provide soft starting, for inrush current limiting.

You may be able to do something similar by limiting demand until the motor is running. But I'd want to test this on a current-limited PSU first.

If your PSU has good current-limiting. you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the datasheet: http://www.kemo-electronic.de/datasheets/m195.pdf

> **Important:** The capacity of the module is max. 20 A! Please make sure
>   that the connected loads do not have a higher current consumption!
>   There are motors, which have a current consumption of e.g. 8 A during
>   operation but require > 30 A during the start-up or in blocked
>   condition! These will destroy the controller.

So i would say the 20amps is the peak value or that its not much over 20.